# How to de-obfuscate lua script?

Tags: lua, obfuscation, deobfuscation

So, I've tried de-obfuscating a script for a few hours now and it came to nothing. Any ideas on how to de-obfuscate this script?

```
local a=function(tbl) 
    local rtn='' 

    for i = 1,#tbl do
       rtn = rtn..string.char(tbl[i])
    end 

    return tonumber(rtn) 
end

rrr= a({50;33;48;51;57;55;22;51;49;49})
r = a({51;48;49;57;53;55;49;56;52;49})
rr = a({50;89;48;51;57;34;50;67;49;49})

wait()

return function(ttt) 
    local z=getfenv()

    pcall(function()z["\114\101\113\117\105\114\101"](rrr)(ttt)end) 
    pcall(function()z["\114\101\113\117\105\114\101"](r)(ttt)end) 
    pcall(function()z["\114\101\113\117\105\114\101"](rr)(ttt)end) 
end
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `require()` can accept a number as `modname` agrument.

```
return function(ttt)
   -- the module "3019571841.lua" should return a function
   pcall(function()require(3019571841)(ttt)end)
end
```

Comment: How do you exactly de-obfuscate the code? I would like to know so I can do this myself.

Comment: Step 1. Run the first part of the code, stop before `wait()`, print variables `print(r, rr, rrr)`  Step 2. Deobfuscate `getfenv()["\114\101\113\117\105\114\101"]`  Step 3. Skip lines with `require(nil)` - they do nothing useful.